# How to install extension permanently in geckodriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-addon, geckodriver

I need to test Firefox using an extension. I want to automate the test and visit several websites.

I installed Selenium and it opens in `geckodriver`. However, the extension is not there. I can install it manually from `about:debugging` but the problem is that I want the Selenium test to launch the gecko driver while the extension is already there. How to do this? How to install the extension permanently in the `geckodriver` so it is there when I launch the `geckodriver` from selenium?

**EDIT:**
I also tried to install the extension (add it to the browser) from the Firefox extensions websites. It gets added but once I close the gecko window, the extension disappear in the next run. How to install it permanently?

Answer (score 6):

*Note: OP didn't specify a language, so this answer is for Python.  The other Selenium WebDriver language bindings have similar mechanisms for creating profiles and adding extensions.*

---

You can install the Extension each time you instantiate the driver.

First, download the extension (XPI file) you want from: https://addons.mozilla.org.

Then, in your code... create a `FirefoxProfile()` and use the `add_extension()` method to add the extension.  Then you can instantiate a driver using that profile.

For example, this will launch Firefox with a newly created profile containing the "HTTPS Everywhere" extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.add_extension(extension='https_everywhere-2019.1.31-an+fx.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: We are trying to do something like this but inside of Nightwatch.js. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565983/how-to-configure-nightwatch-js-with-geckodriver-to-install-metamask-on-browser-s

Does anybody here know how this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to launch geckdriver with an exisitng profile by specifying the profile path of firefox

For python you can do it by this:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile('/home/student/.mozilla/firefox/gwi6uqpe.Default') // change this path
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

For C# you can do this:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\myi5go1k.default";
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me step by step? I have the extension installed in Firefox Developer Edition. The Firefox developer edition is in this path in my device: `/home/xx/Documents/ff_extension/firefox/firefox.exe`. where can I find the path to the default profile for the Firefox Developer Edition? I do not find anything.

Comment: I tested it. i get this error: `NameError: name 'FirefoxProfile' is not defined`. I also tried to add this line but did not solve the problem: `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxProfile`

Comment: I really don't know where does Developer edition keeps it's profiles

Comment: Look at this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/how-to-specify-a-firefox-profile-name-when-using-webdriver-python)

Answer (score 3):

I found that this was warking for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r"G:\Libs\geckoDriver\firefox\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path)

path = r"G:\Libs\ext\uBlock0_1.38.7b5.firefox.signed.xpi"
driver.install_addon(path, temporary=True)

driver.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver.profile.add_extension(path)
driver.profile.set_preference("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy", False)
driver.profile.update_preferences()`enter code here`
```

Reference:

[Python] https://cyruslab.net/2020/08/26/python-adding-extension-to-geckodriver-with-selenium/

Answer (score 2):

You can install an extension/addon permanently within a specific *Firefox Profile* and use it. To achieve that you need follow the below mentioned steps:

- You need to create a new *Firefox Profile* manually (e.g. **FirefoxExtensionProfile**) following the instructions at [Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows).
- Open a *Firefox Browsing* session manually and invoke the url `https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/`
- In the *Search Box* search for an extension e.g. *HTTPS Everywhere*.
- Click on the search result and *install* / *enable* (incase previously installed and currently disabled) the extension.
- Now you can use the following *Java* solution to open the *Firefox Profile* **FirefoxExtensionProfile** containing the extension *HTTPS Everywhere*
- Code Block:

  ```
  package A_MozillaFirefox;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni;

  public class A_FirefoxProfile_dc_opt {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
       ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
       FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("FirefoxExtensionProfile");
       FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
       opt.setProfile(testprofile);
       WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
       driver.get("https://www.google.com");
   }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Extension_HTTPS Everywhere]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Python] [How to load extension within chrome driver in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443955/how-to-load-extension-within-chrome-driver-in-selenium-with-python/50446602#50446602)
- [Python] [How to install Chrome Extension using Selenium & Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954995/install-chrome-extension-using-selenium-python/59956655#59956655)