# How to get rid of the BrowserStack Local extension popup using ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, browserstack

Am just new to automation and trying to automate browserstack. And i successfully logged to browserStack and passed the credentials and clicked on adding chrome extension . There comes the popup and am unable to get the selector for the buttons in the popup.Did any body face across this issue.

Am using an internal tool to automate,behind the scene i guess its using selenium.

Can anybody help me to find the selectors for the popup in browser stack.

Will attach the screenshot[image]

Any help will be hihly helpful,since its a big blocker for me

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase involves adding the [BrowserStack Local](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browserstack-local/mfiddfehmfdojjfdpfngagldgaaafcfo?hl=en) or any other extension as a part of your *Test Strategy* you need to do it programatically.

You can find a couple od relevant discussions in:

- [How to install extension permanently in geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754945/how-to-install-extension-permanently-in-geckodriver)
- [How to load extension within chrome driver in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754945/how-to-install-extension-permanently-in-geckodriver)

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can enable [Enabling Local Testing](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/automate) either programatically through language bindings or through the  command-line interface as follows:

- Using language bindings:

  - Java:

    ```
    import com.browserstack.local.Local;

    # creates an instance of Local
    Local bsLocal = new Local();

    # replace <browserstack-accesskey> with your key. You can also set an environment variable - "BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY".
    HashMap<String, String> bsLocalArgs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    bsLocalArgs.put("key", "<browserstack-accesskey>");

    # starts the Local instance with the required arguments
    bsLocal.start(bsLocalArgs);

    # check if BrowserStack local instance is running
    System.out.println(bsLocal.isRunning());

    #stop the Local instance
    bsLocal.stop();
    ```
- Steps for using command line:

  - Download the matching binary for your [os](/questions/tagged/os): OS X / Linux 32 bit / Linux 64 bit / Windows
  - Untar/Unzip the binary to a folder/directory on your system.
  - Open your command-line interface and navigate to the folder containing the Local binary.
  - Run the binary using the following command:

    ```
    //OS X/Linux
    ./BrowserStackLocal --key ACCESS_KEY

    //Windows
    BrowserStackLocal.exe --key ACCESS_KEY
    ```
  - Configure tests to run with Local Testing connection as follows:

    ```
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
    ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Automate a local hosted URL or internal URL you will have to use BrowserStack Local testing feature. There is no need to add this extension. 
There is one documentation on How to Perform local testing. All the steps are mentioned in the documents. 
[BrowserStack Automate Local Testing](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/automate)

Comment: I am doing testing in the local hosted URL but when I am trying to automate the broswerstack application using the internal tool the pop up is appearing every time to add the extension. and am unable to get any selector for the poup.somehow i need to click the button on the popup to naviagate to next page.seems like a blocker for me