# Error NoSuchElementException if the screen is not active

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I have a script that performs certain actions in the social. networks. If I make the window active (open it and keep it that way), then the script works fine. But if I switch to another application or something similar, then sooner or later NoSuchElementException errors begin to appear.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".PostHeaderActionsButtonMoreIcon"}

Comment: Sounds like the site is using the Page Visibility API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: @pcalkins it looks like that's really the problem. But that's just the reason. Now we need to come up with a solution.

Comment: Have a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772369/headless-google-chrome-how-to-prevent-sites-to-know-whether-their-window-is-foc