# selenium python how to disable Page Visibility API?

Tags: python, api, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I could not find an answer online on how to disable the Page Visibility API. When I make a window not active, my script can not work properly and some buttons can not be clicked, because the site understands that the window is not active.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless Google Chrome: How to prevent sites to know whether their window is focused or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772369/headless-google-chrome-how-to-prevent-sites-to-know-whether-their-window-is-foc)

Comment: @J.Choi is this a python language?

Comment: It is JS and you can execute it using Selenium. And there is a Selenium-Python-ChromeDriver solution in the linked question.