# Selenium Webdriver loading with My local chrome extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanna launch my chrome webdriver with the chrome extension, The chrome extension which I'm trying to attach is my local chrome extension, i.e I have the extension files(manifiest file and other JS files) in my local directory. so when I open the chrome webdriver I want the extension files attached to the webdriver, is that possible can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443955/how-to-load-extension-within-chrome-driver-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load extension within chrome driver in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443955/how-to-load-extension-within-chrome-driver-in-selenium-with-python)