# Trying to load chrome webdriver with extension installed,

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to load my chrome webdriver with extension installed(following the steps mentioned in '[How to load extension within chrome driver in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443955/how-to-load-extension-within-chrome-driver-in-selenium-with-python)') but unable to find the extension installed can you please help me on this, the code I'm trying is.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('C:/Users/john/Desktop/john/v1.10.0.0.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

It just launches and opens the chrome webdriver with google page, I'm trying to open with extension installed is this possible using selenium, can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

instead of just

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you the code written with java, which is working fine

```
File file = new File("path_to_your_extension");

String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addExtensions(new File(path))

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

Comment: It works, but where I get the path to a determined extension?